# tkinter "window.after" loop stopped after overnight Windows sleep/resume

Tags: python, windows, loops, tkinter, sleep

The problem that I'm having is with a small python application that runs in the background and updates every 0.5 seconds using a "window.after" style recursive loop. It works fine normally and even keeps running when the computer is put into sleep mode and (shortly) later resumed, but when the computer sleeps overnight the loop stops repeating on resume. The program is clearly still running in the mainloop since it is responsive, so what I'm trying to figure out is why that loop has stopped.

Below is a simple example of the type of loop I'm talking about:

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime

def looped_function(window):
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    window.after(1000, lambda: looped_function(window))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    looped_function(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on why that would only happen on long-term sleep/resume? Is there a simple way to detect the computer resuming, or the loop breaking and auto-fix it?

Comment: FWIW, you don't have to use lambda here. you can do `window.after(1000, looped_function, window)`

Comment: @Bryan: While true, I think using a `lambda` here is actually clearer and a little more succinct).

Comment: Mandias: Windows had more than one level of "sleeping" (i.e. S1–S3) and in some of them (apparently) your python application is suspended — see [System Power States](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-states). Not sure if and how to fix that though…